# Segmentation fault when I try to launch unity-control-center

Tags: unity-control-center

When I enter the command `unity-control-center` it returns:

```
unity-control-center
libEGL warning: DRI2: failed to authenticate
Segmentation fault (core dumped)
```

Answer (score 0):

The error is possibly due to nvidia graphic card. 
To mitigate the error I used the following command:
`prime-select intel`.

Try opening the unity-control-center now. My unity-control-center was working fine under nvidia graphic drivers but stopped when I changed the xorg.conf by switching to intel graphic drivers for screen. It might be the possible cause of introduction of this error.

Answer (score 0):

What helped me in the same problem just after a fresh installation without the internet (so no updates) was:

1. Update everything (`sudo apt update; sudo apt upgrade`)
2. Update the graphics drivers (`sudo ubuntu-drivers autoinstall`)
3. Reinstall the app with `sudo apt-get install --reinstall unity-control-center`

Answer (score -1):

use "sudo unity-control-center" and enter your password

But why you do that through terminal?

Hope it helps